# Media Query for a specific element on website

Tags: css, media-queries

I am getting tripped up on writing the correct CSS for a media query to kick in when viewing my site on mobile/tablet or smaller screen.

My website is completely mobile responsive however I've created a top green bar for menu buttons.  That is not responsive and I can't figure out how to create two rows for the menu buttons when the site is viewed in a smaller screen.

This is what I have.

```
@viewport {
width: device-width;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 375px) and (max-width : 667px) {
.secondary-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    text-wrap: wrap;
    }
}
```

I would like to add a code in style sheet editor in CSS because that's the only place I know how to make edits.  Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Michael, that still doesn't seem to fix it, even with removing the extra } in the code.

Comment: There's not enough info in your question to help you more. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve